# Direct sum $Z_1 + Z_2 = Z_2 + Z_3$ implies that $Z_1 = Z_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$, and suppose that $Z_1$, $Z_2$, and $Z
_3$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $Z_1\bigoplus Z_3 = Z_2 \bigoplus Z_3$. Then $Z_1 = Z_2$.

I have tried to prove that by taking element from $Z_1$. We can conclude that $z_1=z_2+z_3$. So, $z_3=z_1 - z_2\in Z_1+Z_2$. Now, how can I prove that $Z_3 \cap (Z_1+Z_2)=\emptyset$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong. For example, in $\mathbb R^2$, $$\mathbb R^2=\left<(1,0)\right>\oplus \left<(0,1)\right>=\left<(1,0)\right>\oplus \left<(1,1)\right>.$$ However $\left<(0,1)\right>\neq \left<(1,1)\right>$.